# Exceptions create a class and appear a message

Tags: java

I want to create an exception named IllegalArgumentException.I should appear a message to "There is an exception.All is false".Where should i appear a message?How can i do this ?I have try this: My main :

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{

           int x=5;

       if(x<10)



           }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is an exception.All is false");
         // or System.out.println(" There is an exception.All is false"); ?




       }

    }
```

the class :

```
public class IllegalArgumentException   {


    public  IllegalArgumentException(String il){
         super(il);
  }
}
```

Comment: this exception already exists https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html, Do you want to have your custom statement printed?

Comment: yes  i will edit my post because i was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own exception class via extending `java.lang.Exception`. For example :

```
public class ServiceFaultException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7399493976582437021L;
    private ServiceFault serviceFault;

    public ServiceFaultException(String message, ServiceFault serviceFault) {
        super(message);
        this.serviceFault = serviceFault;
    }

    public ServiceFault getServiceFault() {
        return serviceFault;
    }

    public void setServiceFault(ServiceFault serviceFault) {
        this.serviceFault = serviceFault;
    }
}
```

When you want to use the ServiceFaultException you can use it like below:

```
ServiceFault sf = new ServiceFault("Error Code here", "Error Definition here", "Error Details here");
throw new ServiceFaultException("Error Name", sf);
```

And you can throw exception with throws keyword or you can catch this exception and write to console etc.

**UPDATE**

Your Exception class will be more basic than the example i've given. Below, is your Exception class:

```
import java.lang.Exception;

// Don't forget to serialize your custom exception class (this class).
public class SomethingException extends Exception{
    public SomethingException(String il){
         super(il);
  }
}
```

The main class should be something like this :

```
import com.somewhere.SomethingException;
    public class JavaApplication1 {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    try{
                        int x=5;
                        //  if(x<10){} // you don't need this line.
                        x = x/0;  // The condition to jump into catch scope.
                    }catch(ArithmeticException e){  // You can define your own exception here.
                        throw new SomethingException("There is an exception.All is false");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Don't forget that you can improve your Exception class with a POJO class that contains more specific data according to your needs. In my first Example ServiceFault is the class that has attributes like screenCode, source etc.

Comment: i have eddited the post.If you could see it again i will appreciate it

Comment: i can't notice the difference. which part did you edit?

Comment: sorry but in my main i have something wrong and it doesnt work nor in your answer i have understand where should i put the message " There is an exception.All is false"

Comment: i'll update my post to give you the correct answer. just give me 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This class already implemented check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)